# Using custom colorscale when update the map

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, mapbox

I would like to update the mailbox choropleth colorscale based on a dropdown menu selection.

I found [this](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eempet/15605/update-method-called-within-an-update/?_gl=1*1wt721n*_ga*MTYyOTM3OTMwNC4xNjY5NzU1OTg3*_ga_6G7EE0JNSC*MTY3MDM2OTk4MC4yNS4xLjE2NzAzNjk5ODQuMC4wLjA.#/) which was developed in Python, but I would like to do the same for R/Shiny.

This was what I tried:

**global.R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(geojsonsf)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)
library(mapboxer)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)
library(rjson)
library(sf)

MAPBOX_TOKEN <- "MY_TOKEN_HERE"
Sys.setenv("MAPBOX_TOKEN" = MAPBOX_TOKEN)

MELBOURNE_MAP <- sf::st_read(geojsonsf::geo_melbourne)

places <- as.data.frame(MELBOURNE_MAP) %>% select(SA2_NAME) %>% pull() %>% append("All regions", 0)

places_length <- length(places)

Names <- as.vector(places[2 : places_length])
ColA <- as.vector(sample(1 : 100, size = places_length - 1, replace = TRUE))
ColB <- as.vector(sample(1 : 100, size = places_length - 1, replace = TRUE))

MELBOURNE_DATA <- data.frame(name = Names, ColA = ColA, ColB = ColB)
```

**ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Column", label = "Column", choices = c("ColA", "ColB")),
  h1("Plotly Map"),
  plotlyOutput("plotlyMap", width = "50%")
)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    bbox <- reactive ({
    st_bbox(MELBOURNE_MAP$geometry) %>% as.vector()
  })


  output$plotlyMap <- renderPlotly({

    # The line below is only to show how I transformed the map to geojson
    # st_write(MELBOURNE_MAP, "www/melbourne.geojson")

    url <- 'http://127.0.0.1:6764/melbourne.geojson'
    geojson <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
    
    cnumbers <- c(0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25)
    ccolors <- c("#EDF8E9", "#C7E9C0", "#A1D99B", "#74C476", "#31A354", "#006D2C")
    
    fig <- plot_ly() 
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
      type="choroplethmapbox",
      geojson=geojson,
      locations=MELBOURNE_DATA$name,
      z=MELBOURNE_DATA$ColA,
      #colorscale="Viridis",
      colorscale=mapply(c, cnumbers, ccolors, SIMPLIFY = FALSE),    <- This is a CUSTOM colorscale, and it works
      featureidkey="properties.SA2_NAME"
    )
    fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "Numbers")
    fig <- fig %>% layout(
      mapbox=list(
        style="carto-positron",
        zoom =9,
        center=list(lon=bbox()[1], lat=bbox()[2]))
    )
    fig
  })

  myPlotProxy <- plotlyProxy("plotlyMap", session)
  
  update_plotlyMap <- function(column, region) {
    cnumbers <- c(0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25)
    if (column == "ColA") {
      ccolors <- c("#EDF8E9", "#C7E9C0", "#A1D99B", "#74C476", "#31A354", "#006D2C")
      # cscale <- "Viridis"
    } else {
      ccolors <- c("#EFF3FF", "#C6DBEF", "#9ECAE1", "#6BAED6", "#3182BD", "#08519C")
      # cscale <- "Cividis"
    }
    cscale <- mapply(c, cnumbers, ccolors, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

    myPlotProxy %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("update", list(
        z = list(MELBOURNE_DATA[[column]]),
        colorscale = list(cscale)    # HERE is the issue when I use CUSTOM colorscale
      ))
  }
```

NOTE: When I pass a named colorscale (eg: Viridis, Cividis) it works. Obviously commenting out the mapply line

I also find [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2352) dated 2020. The answer tells exactly what the note above.

Based on the first link, it looks like it works for Python. Is there a way to make it works using CUSTOM colorscale in Shiny?

Comment: I would try `cscale <- mapply(list, cnumbers, ccolors, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)` and `colorscale = cscale`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thank you for your answer. But, in the end, it is the same. It doesn't work. I believe it is because it is a custom scale. It works with named scales as "Viridis", "Cividis" etc.

Comment: The way I propose should work at condition that `cnumbers` contain at least `0` and `1`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, could you elaborate on that? Creating the map with custom colors work. (see: `This is a CUSTOM colorscale, and it works`) on the scale. The problem is when update it.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, I didn't understand. I don't know.

Comment: I can't get your code to render at all. Since that's obviously not the issue you're having, I thought I would at least mention that you won't send a list to `colorscale`. It might be a named vector or potentially a data frame, but a list won't work. Alternatively, you could add your colors to the data frame and use `color` and `colors` in your Plotly graph.

Comment: @Kat, thank you for your comment. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a bit different from your original code. I've added a lot of comments to explain it as it goes. If you have any questions, please let me know.

[image] [image]

Several of the libraries you called weren't used in this code. However, I realize there may be more to your project. I've only included the libraries used here.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geojsonsf)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
```

The user interface didn't change.

```
ui <- fluidPage(                     # create the user interface
  selectInput("Column", label = "Column", choices = c("ColA", "ColB")),
  h1("Plotly Map"),
  plotlyOutput("plotlyMap", width = "50%")
)
```

I don't have any code outside of either the `ui` or `server` (other than the libraries and the call to create the app).

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  data('geo_melbourne', package = "geojsonsf")  # spatial data
  sfm <- geojson_sf(geo_melbourne)              # data frame
  
  set.seed(23)  # seeded for repeatability; region values for coloring
  ColA <- as.vector(sample(1 : 100, size = nrow(sfm), replace = TRUE))
  set.seed(24)
  ColB <- as.vector(sample(1 : 100, size = nrow(sfm), replace = TRUE))
  
  # prepare color scales
  cnumbers <- c(0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 1)        # from 0:1 scaling
  # chosen color for region values
  caolors <- c("#EDF8E9", "#C7E9C0", "#A1D99B", "#74C476", "#31A354", "#006D2C")
  cbolors <- c("#EFF3FF", "#C6DBEF", "#9ECAE1", "#6BAED6", "#3182BD", "#08519C")
  
  # create list of lists (so that scales are numbers and Plotly interprets correctly)
  scaler <- function(scales, colrs) { # scale vector, range in 0 or 1, all unique
                                      # 1 less length of color vector than scale
    niterator <- c(1, rep(2:(length(scales) - 1), each = 2), length(scales)) # iterate over scales
    citerator <- rep(colrs, each = 2)      # iterate over colors
    that <- lapply(1:length(citerator),
                   function(i) {
                     list(scales[niterator[i]], citerator[i]) # create lists of lists
                   })
    that
  }
  
  calr <- scaler(cnumbers, caolors) # create colorscale for ColA
  cblr <- scaler(cnumbers, cbolors) # create colorscale for ColB
  
  # render initial plot
  output$plotlyMap <- renderPlotly({
    
    gbb = geojson::geo_bbox(geo_melbourne) # get box to find the center
    
    # transcribe JSON char into lists of lists
    geoList <- jsonlite::fromJSON(geo_melbourne, simplifyVector = F)
    
    # create the plot
    plot_ly(type = "choroplethmapbox", 
            geojson = geoList,
            locations = sfm$SA2_NAME,
            featureidkey = "properties.SA2_NAME",
            z = ColA,                            # colorvector
            coloraxis = "coloraxis"              # send colorscale to layout
    ) %>% 
      layout(
        coloraxis = list(colorscale = calr,
                         colorbar = list(title = list(text = "Numbers"))),
        mapbox = list(style = "carto-positron",
                      zoom = 9, 
                      center = list(lon = mean(gbb[c(1, 3)]),
                                    lat = mean(gbb[c(2, 4)]))))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Column, {                  # collect input from dropdown
    if(input$Column == "ColA") {            # if ColA selected then...
      plotlyProxy("plotlyMap", session) %>% 
        plotlyProxyInvoke('update',             # update (changes to trace & layout)
                          list(z = list(ColA), coloraxis = "coloraxis"), # trace
                          list(coloraxis.colorscale = calr))             # layout
    } else {                                # if ColB selected then...
      plotlyProxy("plotlyMap", session) %>% 
        plotlyProxyInvoke('update',             # update (changes to trace & layout)
                          list(z = list(ColB), coloraxis = "coloraxis"), # trace
                          list(coloraxis.colorscale = cblr))             # layout
    }
    Sys.sleep(.03) # wait for it!
  })
}
```

Create the maps.

```
shinyApp(ui, server)     # show me my maps
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I understood before that the scale should have at least 0 and 1, but if you include the steps it wouldn't be necessary. Big mistake. Also, the `coloraxis` did the trick.